# Character variable string size in C

Tags: c, char

I'm trying to make a simple C program where printf asks your name and then enter it with scanf  but the output only gives me one letter in the name. This is the code I used:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{

    char cName;
    cName = '\0'; 

    printf("What is your name?: ");
    scanf("%c", &cName);
    printf("Good evening %c", cName);

}
```

Output:

```
What is your name?: Michael
Good evening M
```

I tried putting `[]` and `[20]` beside `cName` when I declared the variable but that didn't work either. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You only read a single character with the scanf statement. Also, as you seem to be aware, the cName is one char too, and needs to be an array. And printf is printing one char. All %c should be %s

Comment: scanf("%c", &cName) reads only a single character. Use "%s" to read a string. (Same with printf)

Comment: Why didn't you **read the documentation of `printf()` and `scanf()`** before using it?

Comment: @TheParamagnetic: in the OP's defense (I know...), the current code is correct *for a single character input*.

Comment: @Jongware well, yes. That's an excuse as long as people have one-character-long names.

Comment: Thanks @jpw 1. The %s worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
char cName[100];
printf("What is your name?: ");
scanf("%s", cName);
printf("Good evening %s", cName);
```

---

Nah... explanation, this is what I forgot about:

1. `char c;` is (most probably) 1-byte-long, that is, it allocates only 1 byte on the stack. Your intention is probably to read the entire string into it, which is wrong. That is why I replaced it with an *array of characters* (limited to 99 characters + null terminating character `\0`): `char cName[100];`
2. `scanf("%c", &cName);` reads only **one** character into your `cName` variable.
   You should use the `%s` format to scan the entire string, and store it into an array (big enough to store all input characters), by passing the address to a newly created variable `cName`.
3. `printf("Good evening %c", cName);` it prints out a single character, same as with `scanf` you should use `%s` instead to print out a sequence of characters from your array until a null terminating character (`\0`) is encountered.

---

> Why for the single character &cName was necessary as 2nd argument, and now just cName for a string ?

This is because we have changed the formatting string and the destination that `scanf` initializes. That is, `scanf` needs to initialize your variable. Your variable is allocated on the stack and what you need to do is to pass its *address*, so that the `scanf` can set its value in an *indirect* manner (through pointer).

In C, to get the address of a variable, whe normally use *an ampersand* - `&`. However, in case of arrays (declared like `char cName[500];`), the name of the array is itself a pointer to its first character. Alternatively, you could use a syntax like `&cName[0]` to obtain the address of the first character.

This is why in case of a single character we would say `&cName` to get its address, and in case of arrays we say simply `cName`.

---

> It is possible to overflow cName array!

Yes it is! Your array is now only `[100]`-character-long. Some *hacker* could now type in more characters, possibly overriding your stack. How can we make it more safe? Very easily! We can limit the length of the string being copied to the array within `scanf` itself by proving *length-specifier*, just like below:

```
scanf("%99s", cName);
```

---

> Hold on a second! My array is 100-character-long, why do you allow only 99 in scanf ?

If you want to treat your `char`-array as a *string* of characters, it should be terminated with (that is, the last character should be set to) a *null terminating character*, expressed by the `\0` constant. And `scanf` appends this character after all input symbols have been read. This last 100th character is reserved for this purpose.

---

> Should I provide %99s to printf just like to scanf ?

No! `%s` is sufficient. When `printf` sees the `%s` format, it knows to print out all characters until a null terminating character is encountered. Additionally, a *length-specifier* in case of `printf` is in fact a *minimum-width-specifier*, which allots a space for the argument in the output stream.

Comment: Just a tiny bit of explanation would be nice.

Comment: Also keep in mind that this code is unsafe - it is possible to overflow `cName` array.

Comment: care to add an explaination why for the single character &cName was necessary as 2nd argument for scanf/printf, and now just cName for a string?

Comment: Better, thank you - 1+. However still nitpicking:  1st: The "string"-terminator is called `null` or `NUL`. `NULL` is something different. 2nd: "*You are trying to read entire string ...*" he is not, as he does `scanf(..., &cName)`. A better wording would be "*Your intention is to read ...*".

Comment: Fine, upvoted already. However claiming his intention to read a string would be wrong, might not be what you want to express ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can also declare a character pointer

```
char *cName;
cName = malloc(20*sizeof(*cName));
```

replace your scanf with this

```
scanf("%s", cName);
```

add this together with other header files

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

and free the dynamic memory after you're done using it

```
free(cName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you must use %s instead of %c. As %c will only scan/print one character. %s should scan/print multiple characters. You will also probably need to use strings. try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char cName [200];
  scanf("%s",&cName);
  printf("Good evening %s.\n",cName);

  return 0
}
```